# Access Body Param NodeJS Express

Tags: json, node.js, express

I have a route

```
router.post('/api/getSessionTimeOut', apiController.getSessionTimeOut);
```

This is in my controller

```
function getSessionTimeOut(req, res) {

    res.send(req.body.session); // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    var options =
    {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://api/json',
        body:
        {
            id: 1,
            method: 'get',
            params: [
                {
                    url: '/cli/global/system/admin/setting'
                }
            ],
            session: req.params.session
        },
        json: true
    };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
        console.log(body, response);
        res.send(response.result);
    });
};
```

After making a POST to the route with `session` as `body` via **Postman**

[image]

I kept getting

```
Red alert! Red alert!: TypeError: Cannot read property 'session' of undefined
    at getSessionTimeOut (/Users/doe/Desktop/express-app/controllers/api.js:50:23) at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/doe/Desktop/express-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) at next (/Users/doe/Desktop/express-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13) at Route.dispatch (/Users/doe/Desktop/express-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3) at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/doe/Desktop/express-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) at /Users/doe/Desktop/express-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22 at Function.process_params (/Users/doe/Desktop/express-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12) at next (/Users/doe/Desktop/express-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10) at Function.handle (/Users/doe/Desktop/express-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3) at router (/Users/doe/Desktop/express-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12) at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/doe/Desktop/express-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) at trim_prefix (/Users/doe/Desktop/express-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13) at /Users/doe/Desktop/express-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7 at Function.process_params (/Users/doe/Desktop/express-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12) at next (/Users/doe/Desktop/express-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10) at serveStatic (/Users/doe/Desktop/express-app/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:75:16) at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/doe/Desktop/express-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) at trim_prefix (/Users/doe/Desktop/express-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13) at /Users/doe/Desktop/express-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7 at Function.process_params (/Users/doe/Desktop/express-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12) at next (/Users/doe/Desktop/express-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10) at expressInit (/Users/doe/Desktop/express-app/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
```

---

**index.js**

```
import express from 'express'
import favicon from 'serve-favicon'
import path from 'path'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'

// Controllers
import apiController from './controllers/api'

const router = express.Router();
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

//For public folder
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(router)
app.use('/images',express.static('images'))
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname,'public','favicon.ico')))
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

router.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.send('Welcome to the backend provisioning daemon to program FortiManager')
});

// app.use( express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.set('trust proxy', 'loopback');


//Fortinet
router.post('/api/getSessionTimeOut', apiController.getSessionTimeOut);
router.post('/api/login', apiController.login);

//Error handling function
app.use((err,req,res,next) => {
    console.error(err.stack)
    res.status(500).send(`Red alert! Red alert!: ${err.stack}`)
});

// app listen
app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`Your server is running on ${PORT}`)
    }
);
```

Comment: Did you configure `body-parser`?

Comment: I have this `import bodyParser from 'body-parser'` on the top of my `index.js`

Comment: @FranciscoMateo I uploaded my `index.js `

Comment: I'm wondering if `app.use(bodyParser.json())` followed by `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded(..))` order matters. Try using `bodyParser.json()` as middleware directly in the route: `router.post('/api...', bodyParser.json(), apiController.getSessionTimeout)`

Comment: try moving `app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));` right after `const app = express();`

Comment: let me know what comes out `:p`

Comment: It works. I'm not sure why and how. Can you please explain to a noob like me ? @GeorgeBailey

Comment: The order of middlewares is always critically important because they process each request in the order they are declared.

In your code, body-parser was populating `req.body` after the request was analyzed by the route. Moving it up stream fixes it.

It is a similar logic error to when you forget to await an async function and it parses the next line that is relying on a result from the awaited function.

Commit to memory that the order of middlewares is always important. It comes up a few times when configuring Express servers. (and Redux mdidlwares)

Comment: For science, I think you could break it again by moving the body parser injection right after `app.use(router)` and it should fix it again if you move it right before `app.use(router)`.

Comment: cool @ihue. let me post explanation in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving

`app.use(bodyParser.json()); app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`

right after

`const app = express();`

Why, because you need to use/register `middlewares` on your server/app before registering any route on your server. This will make sure that every request coming to the registered route is first passed through `body-parsers` and will let the `body-parsers` to do the construct the request data in its specified data structure or format.

Hope that helps

Thanks